# R: Why does append() assign each column of a data frame to a list and not the data frame object?

Tags: r, list, append

It is common to use `append` to assign objects to the next index of the list without specifying the index number. Based on what I have seen suggested to others, I expected `append` to return a list of length 1, where the first index is the data frame, after appending a data frame to a list. However, instead it returns a list of a length equal to the number of columns in the data frame. One explanation for this is that `append` expects a vector, but then this seems somewhat at odds with many of the suggested use cases I have seen.

If `append` is not supposed to assign the entire object, is there an alternative function for adding an object to the end of a list? In the minimal working example below, I show one way of doing it using my own function, but imagine there is function for this.

```
# Generate data
foo <- list()
bar <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)

# Returns length-2 list - BAD!
str(append(foo, bar))

# Expected output
foo[[1]] <- bar
str(foo)

# Kludgey alternative
foo[[length(foo) + 1]] <- bar
```

Comment: A data frame is a [special] list, so you need to wrap it in `list()` so it doesn't get flattened, e.g. `append(list(), list(mtcars))`. Also there's no particular difference between `append()` and `c()` here.

Comment: Yes, I understand this but the questions is *why* and whether there is some alternative function that appends the object, not elements of the object (i.e. vectors in the df list)

Comment: Frankly you should very, very rarely be doing this; growing objects is the second circle of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Use `lapply()` instead.